# How to use a Python Regex to match multiple lines from a PDF file

Tags: python, regex

**PROBLEM**

I am working on a python program that will help me to extract some information from a set of PDF invoices. I am using regular expressions to pull out the following pieces of information (**QUOTE NO., PRODUCT/MODEL NAME etc.**) from a sample pdf file attached [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hMwxo9qRfo-aDmVTS2EdqjO7_O3KUqm2?usp=sharing).

However, I am having a bit of trouble getting a Python regex to work when matching against the text that spans multiple lines.

This a link to the working [REGEX101 - DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qBWlYb/1)

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR…**
I have managed to write the following regular expressions that:

1. Extract QUOTE NO. = `^([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\.) ([A-Z0-9]*)$`
2. Extract MODEL NAME = `^.*\n(?=^DESC:)`

**HELP REQUIRED…**
I can print all the other regular expression except this one `^.*\n(?=^DESC:)`
I, therefore, need help in printing out the MODEL NAME from the python script below.

```
import re
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

invoice = '/home/roy/Documents/pdf_exctract/4.0 Proforma Invoice/Proforma_Test_002.pdf'

with pdfplumber.open(invoice) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

quote_num_re = re.compile(r'^([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\.) ([A-Z0-9]*)$')
model_name_re = re.compile(r'^.*\n(?=^DESC:)')

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if quote_num_re.match(line):
        print(line)
    if model_name_re.match(line):
        print(line)
```

Comment: You must have forgotten `re.M`: `model_name_re = re.compile(r'^.*\n(?=^DESC:)', re.M)`. You actually do not need `^`. `r'^.*\n(?=DESC:)` or `r'^.*(?=\nDESC:)` will do. Also, use `.search()`, not `.match()`. Ah, and do not read line by line, take the string as a whole.

Comment: Yes you won't able to find the second regex because it needs to look at the nextline characters to extract the models, and you are doing it one by one line. So you can directly search for your regex in the whole text and you will see your results

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have made the changes to my regex `model_name_re = re.compile(r'^.*\n(?=DESC:)', re.M)` and code `if model_name_re.search(line):` but I am still unable to get the desired output of the Model Name. Could you please expound on the comment with regards to reading it ine by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it over [here](https://repl.it/repls/DirtyUnrealisticConfiguration#main.py).
`test_str` is your `text` variable.

```
quote_num_re = r'^([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\.) ([A-Z0-9]*)$'
model_name_re = r'^.*\n(?=^DESC:)'

Q_matches = re.finditer(quote_num_re, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
M_matches = re.finditer(model_name_re, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(Q_matches, start=1):
    print(match.group())
    
for matchNum, match in enumerate(M_matches, start=1):
    print(match.group())
```

**Output:**

```
QUOTE NO. RS01234
ISUZU MU-X _
```

Comment: @RoyAshoya tip: you can use `code generator` on regex101. it's not the best but a good way to get starter code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at it for more starter code with regular expressions.

Comment: how do I get rid of the empty line after the MODEL NAME output? This regex `costs_re = (r'^([a-zA-Z]+).*?\s(\d+,\d+,?\d*|0)$')` gives me additional costs but with an empty line after the model name `ISUZU MU-X _`

Comment: It's  because of the new line character. You can strip it like `match.group().strip()`

Comment: Perfect. The output is now clean `print(match.group().strip('\n'))`